# Filter Map e Reduce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, filtro

Tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
$scope.listDeColaboradoresObject.forEach(item => {
  item.listNmAssunto = 
  $scope.relatorioTotalMensagensRespondidasColab
  .filter(x => x.nmUsuario == item.nmUsuario)
  .map(x => x.nmAssunto);
    item.listNmAssunto = $scope.removeDuplicates(item.listNmAssunto);

    item.listDtResposta = $scope.relatorioTotalMensagensRespondidasColab
    .filter(x => x.nmUsuario == item.nmUsuario)
    .map(x => x.dtResposta);

});
```

que percorre esse *array*:

```
0: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Cartão extraviado", nmUsuario: "15", dtResposta: "2018", total: 1}
1: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Novo 012", nmUsuario: "Admin", dtResposta: "2018", total: 2}
2: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Novo 012", nmUsuario: "Administrador", dtResposta: "2018", total: 1}
3: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Novo 012", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 3}
4: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Teste GREAt", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 2}
5: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Thais 23042018", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 2}
6: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "teste Alterado2", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 1}
```

e que me retorna o seguinte *array*:

```
0: {nmUsuario: "15", listNmAssunto: Array(1), listDtResposta: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2975"}
1: {nmUsuario: "Admin", listNmAssunto: Array(1), listDtResposta: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2976"}
2: {nmUsuario: "Administrador", listNmAssunto: Array(1), listDtResposta: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2977"}
3: {nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", listNmAssunto: Array(4), listDtResposta: Array(4), $$hashKey: "object:2978"}
```

**Minha dúvida é como faço para que na hora do *map* eu insira tanto o nmAssunto quanto o dtResposta, dentro do mesmo *array**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta criar o objeto com as duas propriedades e retorná-lo no callback do map

```
$scope.listDeColaboradoresObject.forEach(item => {

  item.listAssuntoResposta = $scope.relatorioTotalMensagensRespondidasColab
    .filter(x => x.nmUsuario == item.nmUsuario)
    .map(x => ({ nmAssunto: x.nmAssunto, dtResposta: x.dtResposta}) );

});
```

Como você está utilizando uma arrow function, a instrução declarada logo após o `=>` é automaticamente interpretada como o retorno da função. Porém como você está declarando um objeto como retorno, é importante deixa-lo entre parenteses, ou o compilador/interpretador irá interpretar as chaves como o início do escopo da função, não como início da declaração de um objeto.

Comment: Muito simples, obrigado @user139742